# Space occurred in loop after IDEA formatting

Tags: intellij-idea

how to avoid space after val in my sample below?

```
for (Exception val : list) {
         ...
}
```

after IDEA formatting i wanna have

```
for (Exception val: list) {
         ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the language??

Comment: now i'm writing java

Answer (score 0):

Settings => Code Style => (Choose your language) => Choose Spaces Tab => Set your desired places to add spaces

Comment: yes, i know about it dialog, but can't find checkbox i need((

Comment: Before property name-value separator ':'

Comment: what IDEA edition are you use? i'm on Community Edition

Comment: @Dragos there is different value. There is an example `x = y >= 0 ? arr[y] : -1;` which is not `enhanced for loop`.